# Where does Windows Server 2012R2 store my config?

Tags: c#, application-settings, exe.config

I installed my c# application application.exe and put the application.exe.config in the same folder! Once I start the exe the config gets transfered to some magical place! Further edits I do in the config are lost, cause the application seems to get the config from somewhere else.
I found some references to a folder called "documents and settings" but I am not able to find it!

Can someone help??

Thanks!

Furthermore: How can I achieve that the application uses the config in the same folder?

Comment: .. is this a ClickOnce app?

Comment: I am not sure if I get the term ClickOnce correctly. It's just an .exe, no installation needed, yeah

Comment: It should be [application name].exe.config in the same folder. Making any edits would mean that you would have to restart the application..

Comment: no unfortunately its not :( edits dont work :(